# Linker error with Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 SDK

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mpi

I tryed to write program with using OpenMP and MPI in Windows 7 x64.
I found tutorial, how install MPI in VS2010

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee441265.aspx#BKMK_debug1

But, when I try compile solution, I get linker errors:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MPI_Finalize@0 referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MPI_Barrier@4 referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MPI_Recv@28 referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MPI_Ssend@24 referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MPI_Comm_size@8 referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MPI_Comm_rank@8 referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MPI_Init@8 referenced in function _main
```

May be I have to install something else? May be HPC Pack 2008 R2 Service Pack 2?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check out step 3 ("Specify additional properties for the project") under Section "Create a C++ MPI sample project in Visual Studio 2010" in the link you provided

The error is informing you that the linker cannot find the libraries containing the defintiions for the various *MPI** functions.  The linker settings (Library directories (3c) and Linker->Input (3d)) are the ones that specify for the linker what libraries to use and where to find them

Comment: I have the same paths in my computer. It is not problem, may be, this libraries contains in other place?

Comment: Do you have `msmpi.lib` in the Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies setting?  If yes, do you have that file in the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 SDK\Lib\i386" directory?

Comment: Yes, but I use C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 SDK\Lib\amd64. With i386 all work correctly

Comment: I think your project is set to be a 32 bit application (thus why it is working for `i386`.  The `msmpi.lib` in the `amd64` folder is for 64 bit applications.  Follow the directions on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx) to set your project to target 64 bit platforms